# python pass variable to import file

Tags: php, python

as i understand it, in php the `require_once('filename.php')` function essentially picks up the content of `'filename.php'` and places it inline in the current file right where the `require_once` call occurs. this enables me to do the following:

```
$ cat caller.php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$a = 'value of variable a';
require_once('callee.php');
?>
$ cat callee.php
<?php echo $a; ?>
$ ./caller.php
value of variable a
```

in other words, the value of variable `$a` is passed to the file `callee.php`.

**is there a way to pass a variable to another file like this in python?** i have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$ cat caller.py
#!/usr/bin/env
a = 'value of variable a'
import callee
$ cat callee.py
print a
$ ./caller.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/caller.py", line 3, in <module>
    import callee
  File "/tmp/callee.py", line 1, in <module>
    print a
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

i guess i could pass the variable as an argument to a function within `callee.py`, but i'd like to not have to do this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try `execfile`.

Replace

```
import callee
```

By

```
execfile("callee.py")
```

Compare to `import`, `execfile` needs more exception handling, you should consider the exceptions will occur in the script. Although I think php needs it also.

Comment: perfect! i was worried it might no be possible. are there any downsides to using `execfile` over `import`?

Comment: Yes, `import` just imports a module while `execfile` executes the files code. So the exception handling is more complicated, [`the reference`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) can help you. But I think in your situation, it seems that you want an `execfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Python, it use the namespace,
just try

```
print callee.a
```

after import callee That will works for your job. And you will find a callee.pyc which is a compiled file in Python.

Comment: in my code `a` contains the path to a file containing a parent class and i want to extend that parent class from within `callee`. in other words, i need to use `a` within `callee.py`, not within `caller.py`.

Comment: You __might__ find a callee.pyc, depending on the implementation you are using.